# Data Cube Finding Max Values of Columns

Tags: sql, cube

I created a cube called Tb_Offers_Cube with the following characteristics. The trouble is using the max function to find the product offered in largest quantity for each city. I keep on getting multiple products for each city yet.

```
The dimensions of the cube are: Tb_Supplier and Tb_Product.
Measure groups table is: Tb_Offers.
Measure aggregates: SUM(Quantity), SUM(Quantity*Price), 
MAX(Price) , MIN(Price).
Dimension hierarchies:

Tb_Supplier:    State > City > Name
Tb_Product:     Product_Packaging  > Name 
                Product_Category > Product_Line > Name

--For each supplier city find the product offered in largest quantity?
```

```sql
    SELECT [Supplier City], [Product Name], max(DISTINCT [Total Transactions Quantity])
    FROM Tb_Offers_Cube
    WHERE [Supplier Name] is NULL
    AND [Supplier State] is NOT NULL
    AND [Supplier City] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Name] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Packaging] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Category] is NULL
    AND [Product Line] is NULL
    GROUP BY [Supplier City], [Product Name], [Total Transactions Quantity]
    ORDER BY [Supplier City], [Total Transactions Quantity] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `max` **product name** to include in your display for each `city`.

```
SELECT [Supplier City]    
    , [Total Transactions Quantity]
    , (SELECT TOP 1 [Product Name] FROM Tb_Offers_Cube WHERE [Total Transactions Quantity] = t.[Total Transactions Quantity]
        AND [Supplier City] = t1.[Supplier City]) AS [Product Name]
FROM 
    (SELECT [Supplier City]    
        , max(DISTINCT [Total Transactions Quantity]) [Total Transactions Quantity]
    FROM Tb_Offers_Cube
    WHERE [Supplier Name] is NULL
    AND [Supplier State] is NOT NULL
    AND [Supplier City] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Name] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Packaging] is NOT NULL
    AND [Product Category] is NULL
    AND [Product Line] is NULL
    GROUP BY [Supplier City]) t
ORDER BY t.[Supplier City], t.[Total Transactions Quantity] DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, although that query does pull the max [Total Transactions Quantity], it doesn't pull the corresponding [Product Name] from the same row. It instead returns the max value of the [Product Name] column independently from the max [Total Transactions Quantity].

Comment: @MattRoberts, I changed the answer to use correlated subquery. Please try